# Why can't i replace the function name by it's return value in this example?

Tags: python, filter, generator

I'm writing a python program to print primes. Here is my code and some comments

```py
# make an odd iterator
def _odd_iter():
    n = 3
    while True:
        yield n
        n = n + 2

# return a lambda funcion to find which number couldn't be divisible by p
def _not_divisible(p):
    return lambda x : x % p > 0

def primes():
    yield 2
    it = _odd_iter() # initial sequence
    while True:
        n = next(it) 
        yield n  # give the first element in the new iterator it
        # When I use code below, filter seems doesn't work well. 
        it = filter(lambda x : x % n > 0, it) 
        # When I use code below, filter works well
        # it = filter(_not_divisible(n), it) 

# print the first 10 primes
prime = primes()
for i in range(10):
    print(next(prime), end=', ')
```

My main question is in the line with `filter`. When I use the function `_not_divisible(n)` in the filter,  I got the output:

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29
```

It's what I want. However when I use function `_not_divisible(n)`'s return value `lambda x: x % n > 0` instead of the function itself, I got the output:

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19
```

It seems that the `filter` doesn't work.

I also test if `_not_divisible(3)` and `lambda x: x % 3 > 0` are same:

```py
# test if _not_divisible(n) and lambda x:x % n > 0 are same, This works fine. 
ita = filter(lambda x:x % 3 > 0, range(20))
itb = filter(_not_divisible(3), range(20))
while True:
    try:
        print(next(ita), end=', ')
        print(next(itb), end=', ')
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

It gave me a good output:

```
1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 10, 10, 11, 11, 13, 13, 14, 14, 16, 16, 17, 17, 19, 
19,
```

So what caused the problem, anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a sneaky one. The problem is with `n`, which you hardcoded in your last test.

```
ita = filter(lambda x:x % 3 > 0, range(20))
itb = filter(_not_divisible(3), range(20))
```

Let's modify the code and see.

```
ita = []
itb = []
for n in range(3, 8, 2):
    ita.append(filter(lambda x:x % n > 0, range(20)))
    itb.append(filter(_not_divisible(n), range(20)))

for a, b in zip(ita, itb):
    print(list(a))
    print(list(b))
    print()
```

This prints out

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

The lambda will always look up the value of `n` when it is called. By the time you call all lambdas in `ita`, they will all see the value `n` had at the end of the iteration, which is 7.

In contrast, when you pass that value to a function and call the lambda from within, you end up "freezing" the value. Because the function has its own local context and `n` is whatever value it was passed during the call. So each lambda in `itb` will look up `n` from a different context each time.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm a little confused after reading your answer. After  the first `for` block, elements in `ita` is three `filter(lambda x: x % n >0, range(20))`, but in `itb`, there is `filter(_not_divisible(3), range(20))`, `filter(_not_divisible(5), range(20)` and the same to 7. And when I have to print them, filter start to calculate. At this time, `n` is 7, so `lambda`'s in `ita` all use 7 to compute so there will be three same lists without 7 and 14. This is what I got in your answer, did I get a correct comprehension?

Comment: @Syvshc That is correct.Every function (lambdas are also functions) have their own scope, which includes parameters and anything assigned within the function. So, when you do `_not_divisible(3)`, within the scope of the function n = 3. But when you do `lambda x: x % n`, `n` is neither assigned to a value, nor passed as argument, so it doesn't exist within the lambda's scope. Therefore, it will look for it in the enclosing scope, which is where you do the loop. This name look up will happen when you call the lambda, at which point n = 7.

Comment: I got it, and I found a new way to use lambda. If I use `lambda x, m=n : x % n > 0`, it works well. Because in every loop, m gets a copy of current `n`'s value, and m won't change with `n`'s changing. Thanks!